# TortoiseSVN loses a revision due to cloud sync

Tags: svn, version-control

I have a file-based SVN repository hosted in the cloud. Somehow I managed to commit revisions 5001, 5002 and 5003 late yesterday, attempt to commit 5004 today... only to have it insist that rev 5001 does not exist. I strongly suspect my cloud sync over-wrote or deleted the file(s), but I can't find a basis to restore what's missing.

Pretty clearly in repo/db/revs all revs up to 5000 exist, as do 5002 and 5003, but 5001 is missing. I know exactly how this rev was generated - is there any way to regenerate it from the files involved? Could I perhaps create a duplicate of the repo, roll back to 5000, and then commit the files again or something?

**Update**: following [TortoiseSVN instructions](https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-howto-rollback.html) regarding reverting to previous versions (e.g. 5000) do not work - they result in error: No such revision 5001. Those instructions recommend against using `svnadmin/svndumpfilter`... but this looks like the only viable option.

Comment: Can you see your missing revision changes in the list of dead transactions??
To do that you need to list all dead transaction by command `svnadmin lstxns repo` and then use the `svnlook info repo -t transactionid`

Comment: Yes and no - it turns out the transaction folders were all dated Dec 3 (12/3)... but the transactions I was looking at were 2/12 - Feb 12, not Dec 2. Date format confusion saw me bark up the wrong tree until I finally got the syntax of svnlook correct.

Comment: Can you also check whether the command `svnadmin verify path` fails? If the verify command fails you unfortunately have no option but to abandon and dump the verisions you have into new repo.

Comment: Yes - that was the conclusion I came to. Mostly the process was easy, if unfamiliar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was simple: use `svnadmin dump` to create a dump of the repo. Since the dump process starts at revision 1, it dumped all the valid revisions, then did not add the invalid revision to the dump. A new repo could then be created from the dump, and subsequent changes recreated.

Many other svn options seem to work backwards from the HEAD revision, causing them to fail in this case.